# NGXS: Update deep level nested array state

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

So I have the following state:

```
[
   {
      name: "Main Tree",
      branches: [
        {
          name: "Branch 1",
          branches: []
        },
        {
          name: "Branch 2",
          branches: [
            {
              name: "Sub Branch 1",
              branches: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

My question is, how do I append another branch under the `branches` in `Sub Branch 1` using state operators? I tried the solution on this [link (State Operators)](https://www.ngxs.io/v/v3.7/recipes/immutability-helpers#state-operators) but it converts the data from array into object which is not the desired output.

Also the above scenario is just an example, my use-case is that it could be an infinite level of sub branches with branches inside them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the above example:

```js
// import { append, patch, updateItem } from '@ngxs/store/operators';

interface BranchTree {
  name: string;
  branches: BranchTree[];
}

type BranchStateModel = Array<BranchTree>;

//..
@Action(UpdateSubBranch)
updateSubBranch({ setState }: StateContext<BranchStateModel>) {
  const newBranch: BranchTree = {
    name: 'Sub 1 of Sub Branch 1',
    branches: [],
  };
  setState(
    updateItem(
      (branch) => branch.name === 'Main Tree',
      patch({
        branches: updateItem<BranchTree>(
          (subBranch) => subBranch.name === 'Branch 2',
          patch({
            branches: updateItem<BranchTree>(
              (subBranch) => subBranch.name === 'Sub Branch 1',
              patch({ branches: append([newBranch]) })
            ),
          })
        ),
      })
    )
  );
}
```

However, you need to implement your recursive solution for the infinite tree based on the above solution.

Read more about NGXS State Operators here: https://www.ngxs.io/v/v3.7/advanced/operators

Comment: unfortunately, the code on the second `updateItem` doesn't work. It creates an error cause the second parameter should be a value or a state operator, not patch.

Comment: @Jed I updated my answer and tested it. It worked well to update the sub-branch, however, I updated it to update the sub-sub-branch. Please note that the state model is `Array<BranchTree>`, and you should implement your own recursive solution based on the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a nested array like

```
tasks
   table
      cols: [{...}, {...}, {etc}]
      rows: [{...}, {...}, {etc}]
```

I used this with success.

```
ctx.setState(
  patch({
    table: patch({
      rows: iif<any>(
        (tasks) => tasks?.some((task: any) => task.id === updatedTask?.id),
        updateItem<any>((task: any) => task.id === updatedTask?.id, patch(updatedTask))
      ),
    }),
  }),
)
```

I have a proposal for an NGXS iterator which I feel is seriously missing.
I'll update that later.